# Iterating through an SQL table, performing query for each row that meets a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to solve a problem that will take a table like so:

```
--- LOG ---
user  time  status
0     001   ARRIVED
0     003   LEFT
0     009   ARRIVED
1     004   ARRIVED
0     012   LEFT
1     008   LEFT
```

and perform the task that is: For every ARRIVAL time find the nearest LEFT time for each user.

```
user  ARRIVED   LEFT
0     001       003
0     009       012
1     004       008
```

However I'm finding it difficult to achieve.

I'm trying to join these two queries together in some way

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT `user`, `time`  FROM LOG
    WHERE `status` = 'ARRIVED'
);

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT `user`, `time`  FROM LOG
    WHERE `status` = 'LEFT' AND `user` = [USER FROM PREVIOUS TABLE] AND `time` >= [TIME FROM PREVIOUS TABLE]
    ORDER BY `time` ASC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: See if any of the pivot table (crosstab) examples [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php) might help.

Comment: What do you mean under 'nearest'?

Comment: try searching a harder, there are lots of questions of this form and in http://dba.stackexchange.com/ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your queries without a join like this:

```
select 
  t.user, 
  t.time ARRIVED,
  (select time from log where user = t.user and status = 'LEFT' and time > t.time 
   order by time asc limit 1) `LEFT`    
from log t
where t.status = 'ARRIVED'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/535P7Qpzzzm9yRbm6FmtrB/0).
Results:

```
| user | ARRIVED | LEFT |
| ---- | ------- | ---- |
| 0    | 001     | 003  |
| 0    | 009     | 012  |
| 1    | 004     | 008  |
```

Comment: On a large data set, this query works very well! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
      a.`user`
    , a.`time` AS `ARRIVED`
    , l.`time` AS `LEFT`
FROM 
    `LOG` AS a
    INNER JOIN `LOG` AS l ON (
            l.`status` = 'LEFT'
        AND l.`user` = a.`user`
        AND l.`time` > a.`time`
    )
    LEFT JOIN `LOG` AS l_prev ON (
            l_prev.`status` = 'LEFT'
        AND l_prev.`user` = l.`user`
        AND l_prev.`time` < l.`time`
        AND l_prev.`time` > a.`time`
    )
WHERE
        a.`status` = 'ARRIVED'
    AND l_prev.`time` IS NULL
;
```

=>

```
user    ARRIVED LEFT
0   1   3
0   9   12
1   4   8
```

time is INT in my example

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

```
select a.user,a.time as 'ARRIVED',min(b.time) as 'LEFT'
from log a,log b
where a.user=b.user
and a.status='ARRIVED'
and b.status='LEFT'
and a.time<=b.time
group by a.user,a.time
```

The table has 6 records and doing a self join to the table will give 36 records, all the combinations from which we can filter out what we need.
Below are the filters
1) Filter based on user as we are looking only for a specific user action
2) Filters that needs to be compared, ARRIVED versus LEFT
3) For any LEFT time we need to look only for the ARRIVED time before LEFT time and it can be same also. (a.time<=b.time)
4) Group by based on user and arrived time will give you list of all LEFT time that are greater than or equal to arrived time for any user.
5) Aggregator MIN is used as we are looking only for the earliest LEFT Time for the given user's ARRIVED Time.

Comment: This first answer looks good but could benefit from an explanation of how it solves the problem.

Comment: You should use proper joins and not propose this archaic syntax.